# What is the BigO of this function

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

The `Big-O` notation concept is not new for me, but I've just seen this code snippet where the author says that it is cubic time or `O(N^3)` and I'm confused, I would say that it is `O(n^2)`, can anybody help me in the right direction?

Thx!

```
long sum = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
  for( int j = 0; j < n*n; j++ ) {
    sum += i - j;   
  }
}
```

Comment: Note the `n*n` in the second `for` loop.

Comment: The outer loop generates `n` iterations of the inner. The inner will, each time, generate `n * n` iterations. So you have `n^2, n^2, ...` iterations. Sum that up and you will get `n * n^2`. Which is `n^3`.

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that subtracting two integers can be done in constant time (as well as incrementing integers, etc.), it is ***O(n<sup>3</sup>)***.

In the inner `for` loop, the `j` counter loops from `j = 0` to `j = n*n`. So that means that each time we start the inner `for` loop, it will perform `n*n` iterations.

We do this `n` times, since the outer `for` loops runs from `i = 0` to `i = n`. So the total number of iterations is `n*n*n`, and thus *O(n<sup>3</sup>)*.

Comment: Makes sense, didn't look properly at the n*n in the inner loop. Thx. I'll accept the answer in 8 minutes (isn't possible earlier)